# Assigning user role in custom module redirect to no route

Tags: magento2, acl

In my custom module i have created ACl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="ABC_CustomReports::top_level" title="TECNO" sortOrder="10" >
                <resource id="ABC_RecommendedOffer::data" title="Recommended Offer" sortOrder="20">
                    <resource id="ABC_GuestRecommendedOffers::guestrecommendedoffersgrid" title="Guest" sortOrder="30" />
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="ABC_GuestRecommendedOffers::guestrecommendedoffersgrid"
         resource="ABC_RecommendedOffer::guestrecommendedoffersgrid"
         title="Guest Offers"
         action="guestoffers/"
         module="ABC_GuestRecommendedOffers"
         sortOrder="20"
         parent="ABC_RecommendedOffer::data"/>
</menu>
```

and controller

```
<?php

namespace ......;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{

protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * Grid constructor.
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{

    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $this->initPage($resultPage)->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Manage Guest Offers'));
    return $resultPage;
}
protected function initPage($resultPage)
{
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu('ABC_GuestRecommendedOffers::guestrecommendedoffersgrid')
        ->addBreadcrumb(__('Tec'), __('Offers'));

    return $resultPage;
}


protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('ABC_GuestRecommendedOffers::guestrecommendedoffersgrid');
}
```

}

when i assign a new user to this module its redirect me to

> abc.com/admin/admin/noroute/denied/key/a4e87d5a8d025664311af3048c6904e59cd20509406fd933727fd8637c6d946c/

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong ACL resource id at `menu.xml`

> `resource="ABC_RecommendedOffer::guestrecommendedoffersgrid"`

should be

> `resource="ABC_GuestRecommendedOffers::guestrecommendedoffersgrid"`

`acl.xml` does not have any resource id like  `ABC_RecommendedOffer::guestrecommendedoffersgrid`

Also

At Action file you donot need to use

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('ABC_GuestRecommendedOffers::guestrecommendedoffersgrid');
}
```

use const variable at here `ADMIN_RESOURCE`

after `protected $resultPageFactory;` add

> `const ADMIN_RESOURCE =
>   'ABC_GuestRecommendedOffers::guestrecommendedoffersgrid';`

Comment: how would you override existing third party plugin(LandofCoder) having acl.xml and menu.xml in order to give permission to access that module to other user roles?. Admin is able to access that module but I also want that module to be accessible by other userroles. i have put up my work over here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326318/magento-2-how-to-override-role-resourcesacl-xml-and-menu-xml. this concept is really interesting it would be great if someone can guide me through this.